# Is it possible to invert colors of a selected chunk of text in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vim, when a selection is made the colors are inverted:
[image]

Is there a way to do this in visual studio code? Or a workaround, such as setting `"editor.selectionBackground": "#000000"` to make the selection background black and some command like `editor.textSelectionForeground: "ffffff"` to make the text color behind the selection white?

Comment: you can customize the selection decoration color

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: do you think this is the first question about this here at SO, and you can read about this in the VSC docs

Comment: I can't find it, is there a command setting I can use?